# Max function not returning the max value in an array

Tags: ruby, string

I have unsorted arrays as `some_array`. When I use `some_array.max` to get the max number, I get the following output. For:

```
some_array = ["1.10.0", "1.11.0", "1.12.0", "1.13.0", "1.14.0", "1.15.0", "1.16.0",
"1.16.1", "1.17.0", "1.18.0", "1.7.0", "1.8.0"]
```

I get `1.8.0` instead of `1.18.0`. For:

```
some_array = ["1.11.0", "1.12.0", "1.13.0", "1.14.0", "1.14.1", "1.15.0", "1.16.0", "1.17.0", "1.18.0", "1.19.0", "1.5.0", "1.8.0", "1.9.0"]
```

I get `1.9.0` instead of `1.19.0`.

To me, it looks like `max` is picking up the last value from the array. Shouldn't `max` print the maximum value in the array? Do I have to sort the array before using `max`? Is there any other way to get max value out of array?

Comment: Maybe my math is wrong...but   1.8 > 1.18.  Now as far as 1.8.0 and 1.18.0...that's a whole different universe.

Comment: I got what you are trying to say. But this is the tag version number. So this will go as per the versioning naming conventions. So as per that 1.8.0 is less than 1.18.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing answers already point out the problem in your code. This is how you may write it:

```
some_array.max_by { |version| version.split(".").map(&:to_i) }
#=> "1.18.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are thinking that they are integers, but they're not - they're strings. So they get sorted [lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). That is to say, treat them like an alphabet. "1.8.0" *is* greater than "1.18.0", because the "8" is greater than the "1" character (in the 3rd position).

Look at the following random strings. They are in order:

1. "abcdef"
2. "abdghi"
3. "adaaaa"

Why are they in order? Because you look at the first character, and compare them. Then look at the next character, and compare them, etc. Now look at your example:

1. "1.18.0"
2. "1.8.0"

Look at the first character of each, it's a "1", it's equal. Look at the next character, both are ".", they're equal. Look at the next characters, "1" and "8". "1" comes before "8". Therefore, "1.8.0" must come lexicographically after "1.18.0".

If you want to treat them like integers, there are a few things you can do. 1) You can write your own sort method in a block, or 2) wrap the strings in some hand-made Version object, and then write the [comparator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Comparable.html) there.

If you need help with these specific ideas, let us know.

Comment: There is no integer that has a decimal point. By the way, there is no float/real number that has two decimal points.

Comment: @sawa Oh I didn't literally mean that the askers thought they were integers. Obviously they are not. I was merely pointing out that while each part of the string can be thought of an integer component, it's important to remember that the whole is a string.

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't max() print the maximum value in the array?

Yes. It should. And it is doing so, as you can see in the results you got.

> Do I have to sort the array before using max()?

No.

> Is there any other way to get max value out of array?

Yes. But you already got the max value.

Answer (score 0):

this method checks character by character.

So, comparing 1.9.0 and 1.19.0 , it will give 1.9.0 as bigger than 1.19.0 because the part "1." is equal in both strings, but the next character is 9 in the first one, and 1 in the second one, so the method will say 1.9.0 is bigger since 9 comes later than 1 in ASCII code.

Comment: It is not (directly) because `9 > 1`. It is because `9` comes later than `1` in ASCII code.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to sort version numbers the [Versionomy Gem](https://dazuma.github.io/versionomy/) helps a lot. It also handles all the edge cases, for example beta and RC versions: `1.8beta < 1.8RC < 1.8`.

Using that gem you must change your code to something like this:

```
require 'versionomy'

some_array.max_by { |version| Versionomy.parse(version) }
```